# Looking for working SQLLite.Data and interop dll with compact framework on windows mobile 6

Tags: sqlite, connection, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

Can anyone provide me, working DLL for sqllite on compact framework,

From the forum i found, that some build has error for compact framework, and i am unable to compile c and c++ binary.

So it will be great if some one provide me working dll of SQLlite.data and SQLite.Interop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I use SQLite in [one of the OpenNETCF ORM implementations](http://orm.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/101801) and it gets tested on WinMo, so SQLite.Interop.dll and System.Data.SQLite.dll in the source code there (look under `OpenNETCF.ORM.SQLite\references\CF35`).